# Error while using latest version of Stream Chat Expo, pickDocument not found

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, getstream-chat

I'm getting an error when installing `stream-chat-expo` library with version `5.17.1`.

I did follow instructions from [this website](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/reactnative/), for an Expo app (React Native).

When I run `npm run ios` I get the follow error.

None of these files exist: * node_modules/stream-chat-expo/src/handlers/pickDocument

[image]

Also seems like `pickDocument` references `expo-document-picker`, which I do have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

are you importing pickDocument somewhere in the app internally other than the default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to clean and reinstall the dependencies. Because if you notice, we don't really export pickDocument from `package/expo-package/src/handlers/index.ts` anymore: https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react-native/blob/v5.17.1/package/expo-package/src/handlers/index.ts

Comment: If the issue still doesn't get resolved, please get in touch with support@getstream.io